# JList,JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jlist

My JList has >100 values. when the screen is loaded the i have set the selected index of the list to 50 and added the JList to a JScrollPane. the value is getting selected but the JScrollPane is not getting adjusted to display that value. can anyone pleases tel me how to do that.

Comment: you have added JList to JScrollPane before selecting value in JList, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.ensureIndexIsVisible(list.getSelectedIndex());` should be enough.

Comment: I have tried that but with no success. anything to do with jscrollpane?

Comment: busUnit.ensureIndexIsVisible(busUnit.getSelectedIndex());
scrollPaneBu = new JScrollPane(busUnit);
scrollPaneBu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));       scrollPaneBu.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrollPaneBu.setAutoscrolls(true);

Comment: Move `busUnit.ensureIndexIsVisible(busUnit.getSelectedIndex());` to the end of the snippet and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There are the following.

```
Rectangle rect = list.getCellBounds(list.getSelectedIndex(), list.getSelectedIndex());
list.scrollRectToVisible(rect);
```

Comment: -1 simply no. There is no _obligation_ to answer a question ;-)